# Why should I clone the object inside the array before updating the state?

Tags: reactjs

```
const [movies, setMovies] = useState(getMovies());
```

```
function handleLike(movie) {
    const movieClone = [...movies];
    const index = movieClone.indexOf(movie);
    movieClone[index] = { ...movieClone[index] };
    movieClone[index].like = !movieClone[index].like;
    setMovies(movieClone);
  }
```

Hi, I'm new to React and I while I was taking an online tutorial the instructor makes a clone of an object from the **movies** array(*movieClone[index] = { ...movieClone[index] };*) and I just couldn't understand why? Because when I try to run the code without cloning the object from the array it works perfectly fine.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37755997/why-cant-i-directly-modify-a-components-state-really

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How deep do I need to clone my state when only updating parts of the state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44653269/how-deep-do-i-need-to-clone-my-state-when-only-updating-parts-of-the-state)

Answer (score 0):

When using the `useState` hook, you should only modify the state variable by calling the setter function it gives you. That's how React knows it should queue re-renders for all the components using that variable. Mutating state directly circumvents this mechanism. Modifying `movies` without using `setMovies` might work in some cases, but it'll break the promises React makes to you about keeping everything updated.